# Bash Script Does Not Execute Instructions

Tags: bash, scripting

Bash Script Does Not Execute Instructions

I have successfully executed the AutoDock Raccoon (www.Scripps.edua) front end which allows the parent program, AutoDock, to dock batches of ligands to proteins.

Once Raccoon is executed, then a bash script, RunVS.sh, is run to sequentially execute AutoDock in a subdirectory of each ligand in the list. The problem is that this script fails.

comp@AbNormal:~/Apps/raccoon/Model/Acetylcholinesterase

```
/Test/Results$ ./RunVS.sh
        ________________________________________________________________
  __________//___________________________/////___________________/____________
  _________/__/__________________________/____/__________________/____________
  ________/____/___________/_____________/_____/_________________/____________
  ________/____/__/_____/_/////___/////__/_____/__/////___/////__/___/________
  _______/______/_/_____/__/_____/_____/_/_____/_/_____/_/_____/_/_//_________
  _______////////_/_____/__/_____/_____/_/_____/_/_____/_/_______//_/_________
  _______/______/_/____//__/___/_/_____/_/____/__/_____/_/_____/_/___/________
  _______/______/__////_/___///___/////__/////____/////___/////__/____/_______
        ________________________________________________________________
                                   ______
                                  /      \
                                 /        \
                                /          \   Raccoon
                                \    /\    /    Virtual
                                 \  /  \  /      Screening
                                  \/ /\ \/        Generator
                                   /\  \
                                 /\  \__\    version 1.0f
                                /  \__\
                               /____\

                 == Press ENTER to start the calculation ==

Docking Pralidoxime_apo-1acl ==================================
Running AutoDock...
[Removing grid maps]
         .
         .
         .
Docking Tabun_apo-1acl ==================================
Running AutoDock...
[Removing grid maps]
Calculation completed.
```

Apparently, there is a problem with the run script, run.sh, in each subdirectory.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Generated by AutoDock Raccoon
#
#
# Specify here the paths for the binaries, if necessary
# autodock = ''

    echo Running AutoDock...
    autodock4 -p "Acetylcholine_apo-1acl.dpf" -l "Acetylcholine_apo-1acl.dlg" 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null
```

I can run the line starting with autodock4 in each subdirectory in a terminal, but this rather defeats the value of Raccoon.

My solution is:

```
for d in $(cat ligand.list)
do
    echo $d'_apo-1acl'
    /home/comp/Apps/Autodock/autodock4 -p "$d'_apo-1acl'".dpf -l "$d'_apo-1acl'".dlg
done
```

This results in:

```
./Run.ligand.list.sh
Acetylcholine_apo-1acl

/home/comp/Apps/Autodock/autodock4: can't find or open parameter file Acetylcholine'_apo-1acl'.dpf

/home/comp/Apps/Autodock/autodock4: Unsuccessful Completion.

      .
      .
      .
```

for the remainder of the ligand.list.

I have tried different combination of quotes is the script with the same results.

What am I missing?

Comment: There isn't enough information here to tell what's going on, but I have two immediate suggestions: In the run.sh scripts, try removing `1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null` and see what errors/messages get printed when they run. In your script, don't try to nest quotes, just use double-quotes around the whole thing and `{}` around the variable name (e.g. `"${d}_apo-1acl.dpf"`).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I get the same result:         comp@AbNormal:~/Apps/raccoon/Model/Acetylcholinesterase/Test/Results$ ./Run.ligand.list.sh
Acetylcholine_apo-1acl

/home/comp/Apps/Autodock/autodock4: can't find or open parameter file {Acetylcholine}_apo-1acl.dpf

/home/comp/Apps/Autodock/autodock4: Unsuccessful Completion.

Comment: @Steve That error message looks like you have the brackets in the wrong place -- the `$` goes outside them, and only the variable name goes inside: `"${d}_apo-1acl.dpf"`

Answer (score 0):

You have at least one [quoting](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes) issue - `"$d'_apo-1acl'".dpf` resolves to the content of the `d` variable followed by a single quote, followed by "_apo-1acl" and then another single quote. Solution:

```
"${d}_apo-1acl.dpf"
```